# При редактировании данные изменяется , но не сохраняется .Как реализовать это в JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если умножить 5 * 5 выходит 25, при редактирование 6 * 5 все равно выходит 25.

***Здесь похожие вопросы***

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7868188/javafx-2-save-edit-in-tablecell

***View***

```
public class Earnings implements List3{

    private ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

       private float a = 5;
       private float b = 5;
       private float c = a * b;

    @Override
    public void add(Person person) {
        personList.add( person );
    }
    public ObservableList<Person> getPersonList(){
        return personList;
    }

    public  void print (){
        int number = 0;
        System.out.println();
        for (Person person:personList){
            number++;
            System.out.println(number+")id ="+ person.getId()+"; position = "+person.getPosition()+"; salary = "+person.getSalary()+" prize = "+person.getPrize()+"; earnings =" + person.getEarnings());
        }
    }

    public void fillEarningsData (){
        personList.add( new Person( 1,"accountant",a,b,c ) );

    }
}
```

***PersonController***

```
public class PersonController {

    private Earnings personImpl = new Earnings();

    //data bundle
    @FXML
    private TableView tablePerson;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> columnId;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Integer> columnPosition;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Float> columnSalary;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Float> columnPrize;

    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Person, Float> columnEarnings;



    @FXML
    private void initialize (){
        columnId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("id"));
        columnPosition.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Integer>("position"));
        columnSalary.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Float>("salary"));
        columnPrize.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Float>("prize"));
        columnEarnings.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<Person, Float>("earnings"));

        personImpl.fillEarningsData();

        tablePerson.setItems(personImpl.getPersonList());

        // the mistake can here   
        columnSalary.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
        columnSalary.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float> t) {
                t.getTablePosition().getRow().setSalary(
                        t.getNewValue()
                );
            }
        } );

        columnPrize.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
        columnPrize.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float> t) {
                t.getTablePosition().getRow().setPrize(
                        t.getNewValue()
                );
            }
        } );

        columnEarnings.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(new FloatStringConverter()));
        columnEarnings.setOnEditCommit( new EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(TableColumn.CellEditEvent<Person, Float> t) {
                t.getTablePosition().getRow().setEarnings(
                        t.getNewValue()
                );
            }
        } );

    }

}
```

***Person***

```
public class Person {
    private int id;
    private String position;
    private float salary;
    private float prize;
    private float earnings;

    // Person
    public Person() {
    }

    public Person(int id, String position, float salary, float prize, float earnings) {
        this.id = id;
        this.position = position;
        this.salary = salary;
        this.prize = prize;
        this.earnings = earnings;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPosition() {
        return position;
    }

    public void setPosition(String position) {
        this.position = position;
    }

    public float getSalary() {
        return salary;
    }

    public void setSalary(float salary) {
        this.salary = salary;
    }

    public float getPrize() {
        return prize;
    }

    public void setPrize(float prize) {
        this.prize = prize;
    }

    public float getEarnings() {
        return earnings;
    }

    public void setEarnings(float earnings) {
        this.earnings = earnings;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Надеюсь правильно разобрался в вопросе...

Как правило подобные динамически изменяемые таблицы проще да и вернее строить опираясь на связанные объекты `.bind()` обширное поле всевозможных Property классов упрощают работу с наблюдаемыми данными и исключают массу ошибок.

Касательно самой проблемы изменяя значение одной ячейки вы не уведомляете о необходимости изменить другую ячейку.Все данные в таблице хранятся как экземпляры ObservableValue порождением которых и занимается собственно фабрика если у вас есть необходимость изменить значение ячейки то тут несколько путей  либо в ручном режиме получить объект наблюдаемого списка и работать с ним либо что проще хранить в экземпляре модели данные уже как элемент Property и располагать (к примеру) логику в экземпляре.Дальше пример кода который надеюсь прояснит сказанное мной:

P.S было не совсем ясно почему поле  `position` в классе Person является экземпляром String а в таблице уже существует как Integer...

```
public class ForTest extends Application {

    private TableView<Model> tView = new TableView<>();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void init() throws Exception {

        tView.setEditable(true);

        tView.getColumns().add(column("First", Model::firstProperty, new NumberStringConverter()));
        tView.getColumns().add(column("Second", Model::secondProperty, new NumberStringConverter()));
        tView.getColumns().add(column("Result", Model::resultProperty, new NumberStringConverter()));

        IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 20).mapToObj(i -> new Model(i * 2, i * 4 + 1)).forEach(tView.getItems()::add);

    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        Scene s = new Scene(tView, 500, 500);
        primaryStage.setScene(s);
        primaryStage.show();

    }

    private <S, T> TableColumn<S, T> column(String title, Function<S, ObservableValue<T>> property,
            StringConverter<T> converter) {
        TableColumn<S, T> col = new TableColumn<>(title);
        col.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> property.apply(cellData.getValue()));
        col.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn(converter));
        return col;
    }

    public static class Model {
        private final IntegerProperty f = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty s = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        private final IntegerProperty result = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

        public Model(int first, int second) {
            setFirst(first);
            setSecond(second);
            result.bind(Bindings.add(f, s));
        }

        public final int getFirst() {
            return firstProperty().get();
        }

        public final IntegerProperty firstProperty() {
            return f;
        }

        public void setFirst(int first) {
            firstProperty().set(first);
        }

        public final int getSecond() {
            return secondProperty().get();
        }

        public final IntegerProperty secondProperty() {
            return s;
        }

        public void setSecond(int second) {
            secondProperty().set(second);
        }

        public final int getResult() {
            return resultProperty().get();
        }

        public final IntegerProperty resultProperty() {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```