# JavaFX и наполнение ComboBox объектами

Tags: java, javafx, gui, combobox

Есть класс `Street`, с описанием объекта типа "улица", который содержит себе `private String name;`, `private int id;`, `private String tymeName` и `private int typeId`, а так же `public` методы для получения значений данных переменных.

Также есть `@FXML ComboBox<Street> streetList;`

*Задача:* нужно вывести список улиц беря названия из переменной `name` с помощью метода `getName`. а при выборе определённой улицы запускать обработку события через `new ChangeListener<Street>() {...}`.

Пытался сделать по аналогии с `TableView` и `TableColumn` через `.setCellFactory` и коллекции.

*Вопрос:* Как сделать, что бы из объекта в список забирался атрибут `name` через `getName`и срабатывал `new ChangeListener<Street>() {...}` передавая выбранный объект для дальнейшей работы.

Метод тыка, в данном случае, не помогает.
Как реализовать поставленную цель через строки понятно. Но вот что получится, если, на пример, в списке будет Ленина и Ленина? Причём первый вариант - проспект, второй - улица, но в выпадающем списке это не должно обозначаться. Опять же можно придумать обход через строки, но, как мне кажется, возможно решить через передачу объектов, а не только строк. В таблицах же данный метод работает.

Comment: [ссылка](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/551135/181014) - пример работы с наблюдаемыми объектами Обратите внимание на класс модель и гетеры

Comment: Данный пример применим только к табличным классам, но не к остальным контролам. Изначально пытался решить вопрос именно таким методом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поочередно отвечаю на вопросы.

> нужно вывести список улиц беря названия из переменной name с помощью
>   метода getName

```
streetList.setCellFactory(p -> new ListCell <Street> () {

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Street item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            setText(item.getName());
        } else {
            setText(null);
        }
    }
});
```

> а при выборе определённой улицы запускать обработку события через new
>   ChangeListener() {...}.

```
streetList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) - > {
    //тут описываешь логику лисенера
});
```

тут я использовал лямбду, а не `new ChangeListener()...`

> Но вот что получится, если, на пример, в списке будет Ленина и
>   Ленина? Причём первый вариант - проспект, второй - улица, но в
>   выпадающем списке это не должно обозначаться

У тебя будет и проспект и улица, если объекты `Street` будут разные ( необходимо переопределить методы `hashCode()` и `equals()`)

**UPDATE**

По поводу картинки в коментарии, возможны 2 пути.

1. Переопределить метод `toString()` в классе Street
2. Переопределить `buttonCell` следующим образом

   ```
   streetList.setButtonCell(new ListCell < Street > () {
   @Override
   protected void updateItem(Street item, boolean empty) {
       super.updateItem(item, empty);
       if (item != null && !empty) {
           setText(item.getName()); // или любую другую логику тут можно написать
       } else {
           setText(null);
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Благодарю, половина задачи выполнена. Остался только один момент: Список успешно выводится и событие забирает именно объект, но при выборе элемента списка в текстовое поле подставляется следующее:  
  
![Картинка с ComboBox](http://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2016/08/f9c6e1c1b7814996eb33004bade00f46.png)

Что ещё нужно переопределить, что бы выбранный элемент отображался корректно?

Comment: @Инженер-погромист см апдейт ответа

Comment: Спасибо, @AndrewBystrov! Вопрос полностью исчерпан. Образец класса, который использовал, добавил ниже.

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к ответу @AndrewBystrov. Чтобы в текстовом поле ComboBox после выбора элемента также отобразился один из его аргументов, необходимо прописать конвертер:

```
public class StringConverterStreet extends StringConverter<Street> {

    @Override
    public String toString(Street street) {
        return street == null ? null : street.getName();
    }

    @Override
    public Street fromString(String string) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Использовал его перед

```
streetList.setConverter(new StringConverterStreet());
streetList.setCellFactory(p -> new ListCell <Street> () {
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(Street item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (item != null && !empty) {
            setText(item.getName());
        } else {
            setText(null);
        }
    }
});
```

**UPDATE**

Воспользовался советом @AndrewBystrov и вместо конвертера просто переопределил метод `toString`. В результате получилось следующее:

```
public class Street {
    private int id, typeId;
    private String typeName, name;

    public Street() {
        Street(null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Street(...) {
        ...
    }

    public String getName () {
        return name;
    }

    ...

    @Override
    public String toString () {
        return typeName + " " + name;
    }
}
```

Спасибо большое за помощь!

Comment: Я конечно не уверен, но это не совсем то. Если посмотреть javadoc к методу setConverter, то там написано следующее Converts the user-typed input (when the ComboBox is editable) to an object of type T, such that the input may be retrieved via the value property. Поэтому это не совсем то, что надо. Сейчас дополню свой ответ для картинки из комента